# uploading app to google play - paid and free

Tags: google-play

I'd like to ask something. I'm going to upload my app to google play. But I would like it to be free in few countries and paid in other countries. My question is - is it possible to do that within ONE UPLOAD (and possibly choose those options separately for each country), without uploading app twice (once paid, once free)? Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

As far I know this is not possible. You can set different prices for different countries but the price will be at least around 0.50$. Just published two editions, that is not hard with Android Studio. (you need to use two different package names of cause)

Another way would be freemium so let the app for free in that counties you like and make it to shareware on the other countries. But you need to find out yourself the user's location.